# Estimating risk parameters from observed choices

Tags: risk

My background is in labor economics/applied micro but I am currently working with data collected from a field experiment. My experimental/micro skills are rusty to say the least.

In my data, I observe individuals choosing one of the choices $A, B, C, D$. The value of the choice is realized after the choice. I know that

$$E(A) <= E(B) <= E(C) <= E(D)$$
$$VAR(A) <= VAR(B) <= VAR(C) <= VAR(D)$$

If I assume that $A, B, C, D$ are continuous, independent and normally distributed and individuals are aware of expected payoffs $E(i)$ and variances $VAR(i)$.

- Is there a way to estimate a expected risk aversion parameter (e.g. CRRA) for a group of people?
- Would it make sense to compare these risk estimates from two groups of people, say men and women or high educated and low educated?

I would appreciate if you guys could come up with some relevant literature.

Comment: I quess I should add, that outcomes from lotteries are by construction continuous but nothing limits them to be positive.

Comment: Are these lotteries for money? You'd need to control for diminishing marginal utility of money before you could elicit risk attitudes, no? I've read stuff on [Prospect theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prospect_theory) which discusses how to elicit these sorts of attitudes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am aware of prospect theory and I would probably be able to control for wealth.

This goes somewhat beyond my original question, though. I would like to find references on estimating preference parameteres 1.) from field experiment data 2.) when outcomes are continuous instead of discrete. I have not yet encountered an experimental paper with other than discrete lotteries.

Comment: http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.2307/30034997 This paper is a good start.